# EKCalendar on my ipad application

Tags: ios

I want access to the Native Calendar on my application. It is referred so many links, but it still could not done that process. The events are shown on my calendar. Setting the time and date based alert the user also. Any solution for me much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by the "Native Calendar". Do you mean that you need a calendar view which displays months and days of the week?

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear.

Comment: Are u using swift or objective-c?

Comment: question is very unclear

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this.

....>In appdelegate

---

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                    message:notification.alertBody
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}

// Request to reload table view data
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:self];


}
```

....>create reminder-SecondClass(Save Action)

```
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;

    localNotification.alertBody = self.EventText.text;

    localNotification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    localNotification.alertAction = @"Show me the item";

    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] +1;

    NSUserDefaults *Defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [Defaults setObject:dateString forKey:@"eventdate"];
    NSLog(@"Datepicker Date..%@",dateString);

    [Defaults synchronize];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Notification" object:self];

    // Dismiss the view controller
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

//First Class

--->viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reloadTable)
                                             name:@"Notification"
                                           object:nil];
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [AlarmArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// Display notification info
[cell.EventText setText:localNotification.alertBody];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"dd-MM-yyyy"];

DateString=[dateFormat stringFromDate:localNotification.fireDate];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

NSString *TimeString=[dateFormat stringFromDate:localNotification.fireDate];

[cell.TimeLabel setText:[TimeString description]];

NSLog(@"Datepicker Date..%@",DateString);

[cell.EventDate setText:[DateString description]];
```

So it works finely.